layer.materialize() function not copying all features within layer
What could cause the layer.materialize() function to not copy all the features within a layer?
Similar Post:
layer.materialize() does not copy all features
Steps to reproduce:

Drag an s57 file in qgis to load the layers contained within

Choose one layer and convert it to a geopackage file (I chose the "LIGHTS" layer. Further experimenting revealed that this issue does not occur with some layers)

Remove all layers except the geopackage layer created in step 2

Execute the following code to try to create a memory layer from the geopackage layer chosen in step 2:


for curLayer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(curLayer.allFeatureIds())
    print(request.filterFids())
    clone = curLayer.materialize(request)
    print(clone)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clone)

Result: A cloned layer with all the attributes but none of the features.

Upon further research I realized something of note:
After creating the geopackage layer in step 2, I deleted all columns (attributes) of the layer that contained null values for any features. After doing so, I got a memory layer containing all features ids.

I proceeded with the ENC file (S-57 format) and executed your four steps and did not get anything weird i.e. a cloned layer with all the attributes including features.

@Taras What s57 file did you use?
I used several files from this website:
https://charts.noaa.gov/InteractiveCatalog/nrnc.shtml#mapTabs-2
Specifcally, I tested with the following charts:
US5NYCFJ.000
US5FL54M.000

I used files from the Office of Coast Survey: https://charts.noaa.gov/ENCs/ENCs.shtml

One more question, thank you for your quick replies.
@Taras What operating system are you running qgis on? And what version?
I am running the latest version of qgis on linux.

Also, the layer I performed the 4 steps with is the "LIGHTS" layer.

I am on Windows 11 with QGIS 3.34.8-Prizren

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
